# numpy - 1 field value in 3d array from a 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this issue, I'm trying to build a 3D array where I need later to overwrite eg. [:,:,5] with a value from a 1D array. My arrays look like this in `numpy`:

3D:

```
[[[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.    0.]
  [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.    0.]
  [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]

 [[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.    0.]
  [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.    0.]
  [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]

 [[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.    0.]
  [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.    0.]
  [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]

 [[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.    0.]
  [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.    0.]
  [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]

 [[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.    0.]
  [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.    0.]
  [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]

 [[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.    0.]
  [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.    0.]
  [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]

 [[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.    0.]
  [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.    0.]
  [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]

 [[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.    0.]
  [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.    0.]
  [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]

 [[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.    0.]
  [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.    0.]
  [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]

 [[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.    0.]
  [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.    0.]
  [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]]
```

1D:

```
[ 1806.    1092.     150.     150.    2669.     150.     150.     150.
   310.    7181.85]
```

.. and what I want is this:

```
3d[0][0][5] = 1d[0]
3d[0][1][5] = 1d[0]
3d[0][2][5] = 1d[0]
3d[0][3][5] = 1d[0]
3d[1][0][5] = 1d[1]
3d[1][1][5] = 1d[1]
3d[1][2][5] = 1d[1]
3d[1][3][5] = 1d[1]
```

and so on. I have been trying somthing like this:

```
list_product_pricegroup[:,:,5] = migrete_array[:]
```

without any kind of luck, hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: can you update your code for array creation? please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array `list_product_pricegroup` is 10x4x6 and `migrete_array` is a 1-D vector of 10. Since you index (5) the array `list_product_pricegroup` before assignment, it is now a 10x4 matrix. Then you need to promote `migrete_array` to a 2-D array of size 4x1 to be broadcasted, as such:

```
list_product_pricegroup[..., 5] = migrete_array[:, None]
```

Comment: Thanks, its working close on what i want, but the numbers now going from 

 [[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.    0.]
  [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.    0.]
  [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
  [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]]

to

[[  0.00000000e+00   1.50000000e+02   1.00000000e+01   3.00000000e+02
     2.50000000e+01   7.18185000e+03]
  [  1.00000000e+00   2.50000000e+01   2.00000000e+00   7.50000000e+01
     7.00000000e+00   7.18185000e+03]

Comment: yes, I thought this is how you wanted them to be, according to what I understood from the question

Comment: yes and no :), i want the value moved to the 5 inx and its true, if i do the same just type static number eg. 1000.0 its working fine, and around 50% work fine but som of the numbers not are moving currect there giving the funny numbers you see when i trying your code of, its only this migrete_array[:, None] part there make troblue now, orter are like this as is shut be [[   0.  150.   10.  300.   25.  150.]
 [   1.   25.    2.   75.    7.  150.]
 [   4.    0.    0.    0.    0.  150.]
 [   5.    0.    0.    0.    0.  150.]]

Comment: nevermind, its working i'm trying to print out print(list_product_pricegroup[9][3][5]) and its working as i shut be, thanks a lot :)